# How to enter bios for motherboard nec ms-7479

Tags: bios

I tried del and it doesn't work. I look everywhere on the net and couldn't find any.

I am looking for pages where it is listed how to get into bios.

I went to https://www.nec.com/en/global/solutions/index.html

And I couldn't find anything.

What's the button to press?

Comment: Try F1, F2, F12 or Ctrl+Alt+Esc. You might need to press and hold F2 until you enter the BIOS.

Comment: NEC motherboards are almost always F2

Comment: Where is it written?